# Add parent variables inside an json object while deserialize in jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I wanted to add extended class variables inside and jsonobject during deserialization in jackson.

ParentResponse Class :

```
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class ParentResponse extends DefaultResponse {

@JsonProperty("parentname")
private String parentName;

// Getter and setter
}
```

DefaultResponse Class :

```
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class DefaultResponse{

@JsonProperty("status")
private String status;

// Getter and Setter


@JsonProperty("responseInfo")
    public JSONObject responseInfo() {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
        jsonResponse.put("status", this.status);
        return new JSONObject();
    }
}
```

```
public class ResponseResource {
public static void main(String[] args) {
ParentResponse response = new ParentResponse();
        response.setStatus("success");
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response));
}
}
```

This returns

```
{
    "status": "success",
}
```

My Requirement is

```
{
"responseInfo" : {
     "status" : "success"
}
```

Is this possible without customSerializer in jackson ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your method `responseInfo()` you can declare a method returning a single-entry Map that would serve as a *getter*.

***Note*** that this method doesn't require any data-binding annotations, it just needs to be named as a conventional getter in order to be treated by Jackson as a getter.

To avoid duplicating `"status"` property as a part of the attribute `"responseInfo"` and as a representation of the `status` field while serializing `DefaultResponse` you can either

- Prevent Jackson accessing it by not exposing a getter (which might be not convenient because you might need a getter).
- Another way is to annotate the field with `@JsonIgnore`, that would cause the `status` to be omitted during both *serialization* and *desrialization*.
- The most flexible solution is to make use of the `access` attribute of the `@JsonProperty` annotation because it gives more control. For instance, if assigning `access` attribute to `JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY` it would be taken into account while deserializing JSON, but excluded during serialization.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Setter
@Getter
public static class DefaultResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "status", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String status;
    
    public Map<String, String> getResponseInfo() {
        return Map.of("status", status);
    }
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ParentResponse response = new ParentResponse();
    response.setStatus("success");
    
    String jsonResponse = new ObjectMapper().writer()
        .withDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(response);
    
    System.out.println(jsonResponse);
}
```

*Output:*

```
{
  "responseInfo" : {
    "status" : "success"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Is there a way i can avoid duplicate of status key in root object ? @Alexanser Ivanchenko

Comment: using @JsonIgnore solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: @ManivannanR There's more flexible solution than `@JsonIgnore`, instead you use `access` attribute of the `@JsonProperty`. See the updated answer.